# Test Results Directory Location for Instruments

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-instruments

Using the Apple developer tool Instruments, where do screenshots made with target.captureScreenWithName end up.  I've heard the "test results" directory -- but where is that?

Comment: I should be clear here.  I mean when you are using UIAutomation via Instruments with an iOS device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It defaults to the current user's desktop directory:
~/Desktop/Run 1

Where 1 is a number incremented by instruments. Every time you run it, that increments. Insider there you may have a plist with your results, and any screenshots. In Instruments 4.2 and later you can specify where these "Run X" directories go, even when running instruments from the command line.